# how is std::set (red/black tree) forward iteration implemented?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl

if i did an inorder traversal of a balanced BST from smallest to largest value, i'd use a DFS which maintains a stack of size lg(n). but if I needed to find the inorder successor of an arbitrary node, it's a worst case lg(n) operation. but if I wanted to iterate in order, id need to find the inorder successor repeatedly for each node yielding O(n*lg(n)). Does std::set use some trick for inorder iteration, or does it really cost O(n*lg(n)), or is the time cost amortized somehow?

Comment: I think that typically each node of the tree contains a pointer to the parent  in addition to the left and right node pointers.  So an iterator referencing a particular node can navigate whichever way it needs to in the tree in order to get the next value (or previous value).

Comment: Yeah I had considered that too, but now you’ve got a pointer to parent, a pointer to each subtree, and now two more pointers to be stored per node for next and prev. That’s 66% size increase in the memory penalty per node. Plus, remove and insert and possibly rebalance gets complicated but still doable. So yeah ok that’s a space trade off to avoid painful iteration, but still, I’m wondering if there is some better trick “they” use that’s “free” or linear amortized

Comment: You don't need next and prev pointers. With a parent pointer, computing next/prev  is amortized constant time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no trick in the in-order iteration; all you need is an O(1) mechanism for finding the parent of the current node.

The in-order scan traverses each parent-child edge exactly twice: once from parent-to-child and once from child-to-parent. Since there are the same number of edges as non-root nodes in the tree, it follows that the complete iteration performs Θ(*n*) transitions to iterate over *n* nodes, which is amortised constant time per node.

The usual way to find the parent is to store a parent link in the node. The extra link certainly increases the size of a node (four pointers instead of three) but the cost is within reason.

If it were not for the C++ iterator invalidation rules, which require that iterators to elements of  ordered associative containers must not be invalidated by insertion or deletion of other elements, it would be possible to maintain a stack of size O(log *n*) in the iterator. Such an iterator would be bulky but not unmanageably so (since log *n* is limited in practice to a smallish integer), but it would not be usable after any tree modification.

Comment: Maintaining the stack in the pointer may be problematic because of the iterator invalidation rules.

Comment: The “parent-child 2x traversal per edge overall” expl. was the insight I was looking for. Right on.